# How to search Arabic from database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to search Arabic word contain ( , أ , إ ,ا ) by entering ( ا )  return all data contain ( , أ or إ orا ) in PHP.

For example: search for (اياك نعبد واياك نستعين) return (إياك نعبد وإياك نستعين).

Comment: What kind of "search" do you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on which side you will try to solve the problem ,from Db side or the programming language your are using php & Javascript etc ...

Also which type of data your are searching for fixed format data Like " Hadith with tashkeel or Quran " or data entered by the users and there is no fixed format "احمد" & " أحمد " 
If you are using php you can You can use this library [here](http://www.ar-php.org/I18N/Arabic/Docs/I18N_Arabic/_Arabic---Query.php.html) it will help you to search in Arabic with all cases of the letter check the [example](http://www.ar-php.org/I18N/Arabic/Examples/Query.php) also

IF you want to use the DB side you need to work with MATCH & AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE

also you can use regular expressions to solve this problem by adding all letter cases on your query

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Try this in header

Comment: And how does that help?

Comment: If you are using special character to search you must use UTF-8 character set.

Comment: And for which kind of "search" does that help? If I simply add the meta tag you've mentioned, nothing triggers any kind of search in my browser

Comment: It will user for GET or POST method search. so entire page with response as UTF-8 encoding